# Get the word after a match in a line when line has multiple match

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk

I have a big text file with content as below:

```
Register foo1 ... Register foo2 ... Register foo10...
Register foo20 ...
Un-Register bar1 ... Register foo21 ...
```

I wrote below bash script, which will work only if there is one "Register" per line, but how to get all foo's in same line?

```
#!/bin/bash
file=/tmp/log
grep -e 'Register\s' $file | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v Un-Register | while read -r line; do
    #do something with $line
done
```

Comment: expecting: foo1 foo2 foo10 foo20 foo21, I am okay using Perl as suggested below, thanks.

Comment: ok, you have perl and awk answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
perl -pe 's/\s+Register/\nRegister/g' file |
  grep -oP '^Register\s+\Kfoo\S*'
```

#### Output :

```
foo1
foo2
foo10...
foo20
foo21
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, how is it matching the line starting with Register?, you used `\s+Register`, which should match only space followed by Register, correct?.

Comment: Because the first command is there only to put `Register` at the beginning of lines. So, this is already the case for the first line, not modified, and the next `grep` command will do the match as it should

Answer (score 0):

here's a perl one-liner to find the word after "Register" but not "Un-Register", and all the words from a line will be kept on a line

```
$ perl -nE 'say "@{[/(?<!Un-)Register\s+\K\S+/g]}"' file
foo1 foo2 foo10...
foo20
foo21
```

A less dense version:

```
$ perl -nE '
      @words = /  (?<!Un-)        # preceding characters are not "Un-"
                  Register \s+    # must have "Register" followed by whitespace
                  \K              # disregard the previous from matching
                  \S+             # capture the next non-whitespace characters
              /gx;                # "g"lobally on this line
      say "@words";
  ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex `awk` solution to get the job done:

```
awk '{
   s=""
   for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)
      if ($(i-1) == "Register")
         s = sprintf("%s%s", (s==""?"":s OFS), $i)
   print s
}' file

foo1 foo2 foo10...
foo20
foo21
```

Answer (score 0):

`egrep -o '(^|[^-])Register \w*' file | awk '{print $2 }'`

- first grep filters `Register word` (and not `Un-Register`) and print the matches in new lines (`-o` option)
- And `awk` prints only the word